# display select results inside anonymous block

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, pls-00428

I'm trying to debug a SELECT inside a procedure, and I'm trying to this using a anonymous block. I would like that SQL Developer simply return the last SELECT statement, but I get the error:

```
ORA-06550: line 21, column 5:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
```

Inside the procedure, I have an INTO for that select, but is there a simple way that I can simply get the results for the last SELECT statement for my debugging? I'm using anonymous block and variables so that the code is as similar as possible from what's actually inside the procedure, so that I don't have to change the code

```
set serveroutput on format wrapped;
DECLARE
  p_cd_doc_type number;
  p_dc_doc_code varchar2(200);
  p_dt_base date;
  p_qt_days number;
  p_vl_mov_total number;
  p_qt_transac number;
  v_dt_max date;
  v_dt_min date;
begin
  p_dt_base := sysdate;
  p_qt_days := 1;

  v_dt_max := trunc(p_dt_base) + 1;
  v_dt_min := v_dt_max - p_qt_days;
  p_vl_mov_total := 0;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_dt_max = ' || v_dt_max);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_dt_min = ' || v_dt_min);

    select *
    from tb_cad_cliente a join tb_trn_transacao b
      on a.cd_cliente = b.cd_cliente 
    where a.cd_doc_type = p_cd_doc_type
    and a.dc_doc_code = p_dc_doc_code
    and b.dt_row between v_dt_min and v_dt_max
    and b.cd_status = 3;
end;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try with this, to print your result easily:

```
declare
your_variable varchar2(19);
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('init..');
 FOR x IN (SELECT      your_column
                 FROM you_table
                 where rownum<2
             order by 1)
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(x.your_column);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

For oracle 12c or higher

```
declare
    rfc sys_refcursor; 
begin
    open rfc for select * from table;
    dbms_sql.return_result(rfc);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to return the value of the select it needs to be *selected into* a container (a reference cursor or REF CURSOR). In your Declare you should include `ref_cursor_out SYS_REFCURSOR;`
and change your select to:

```
select * into ref_cursor_out ...
```

In SQL Developer there is an option (I am a Toad user, so I forget where in SD) that tells the IDE to load the result set into a grid to view.

*[edit: per comment from @DCookie, Thanks for the catch!]*

Comment: If i add a   tblresult REF CURSOR; before the begin, I get a PLS-00201: identifier 'CURSOR' must be declared

Comment: Your declaration of ref_cursor_out should be "ref_cursor_out SYS_REFCURSOR;"

Comment: Tks @DCookie. it compiles and all... I use the open tblresult for select * from (...) . I've been searching and digging... how do I print the tblresult? 100% samples are results from procs. NONE regarding anonymous blocks.. :-/

Answer (score 0):

**Error**

For what I know, whatever tool you use to debug, the pl/sql blocks(anonymous and  named) should be **valid** for the **PL/SQL compiler**.
The fact is that your block doesn't result valid for the PL/SQL compiler, and your **error** is there to tell you, and is coming out from the **PL/SQL compiler** and **not** from the **Sql Developer**!

> PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected
>   in this SELECT statement
>       Cause: The INTO clause of a SELECT INTO statement was omitted. For
>   example, the code might look like
>   SELECT deptno, dname, loc FROM dept
>   WHERE ... instead of SELECT deptno,
>   dname, loc INTO dept_rec FROM dept
>   WHERE ... In PL/SQL, only a subquery
>   is written without an INTO clause.
>       Action: Add the required INTO clause

and

> ORA-06550: line string, column string:
>   string
>       Cause: Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>       Action: None

**Why error**

When an Pl/sql error appear, you only have the choice to investigate in the **code** and in the **manuals:**
[Resolution of names in static SQL statements](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/nameresolution.htm#LNPLS99882)

---

**PS:**
The route is always the same:

**[How to ask](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#before)**

**[All the "oracles" are here:](http://tahiti.oracle.com/)**

**[Sql Developer](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/doc.112/e12152/toc.htm)**

Comment: Tks for the info. I'm aware of all that, and I did more than an hour of searching, and I couldn't find a simple way to solve my problem without creating types. After all the investigation, I still couldn't find a simple way of solving this. Maybe there is no simple way, and that's the answer. I simply don't know, even after searching. The INTO works great in my proc. Just need to know how to do it in an anonymous block, and display it on SQL Developer

Comment: This answer can give you an idea: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265160/to-char-of-an-oracle-pl-sql-table-type

Answer (score 0):

I recently changed from MSSQL to PLSQL and I miss the return values as tables from procedures for analytical purposes. I wrote simply dynamic query that return table by two steps. Maybe someone use it:

```
/* 
rkry20150929: Return table from anonymous block 
*/
declare
v_stmt varchar2(1000);
c int;
BEGIN
 select count(*) into c from user_tables where table_name = upper('tmp_result');
 if c>0
 THEN 
  v_stmt := 'truncate table tmp_result';
  execute immediate v_stmt; 
  v_stmt := 'drop table tmp_result';
  execute immediate v_stmt; 
 end if;
 v_stmt :='CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_result on commit preserve rows AS ';
 v_stmt:= v_stmt || 
 /*-----THERE FILL SQL COMMAND-----------*/'
 SELECT ''Result select to table in anonymous block '' MyColumn FROM DUAL
 ';/*-----THERE FILL SQL COMMAND-----------*/
 execute immediate v_stmt;
 End;
 /*FIRST EXECUTE TO HERE */
SELECT * FROM tmp_result;
```