# Return cursor results from anonymous block

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql, cursor

I have the following SELECT which I want to change into an anonymous block (need to use an anonymous block as doing it within Java and do not have access to created stored functionality) in order to remove the use of the literal into a bind variable:

```
SELECT IL.LAT_NUM, IL.LNGTD_NUM
FROM ITEM_LOCATION IL
WHERE IL.ITEM_ID = 294341;
```

I have two anonymous blocks created but am unable to find how to return the values created in both:

1)

```
DECLARE
    itemID number;
    latitude number;
    longitude number;
BEGIN
    itemID := 294341;

    SELECT 
        IL.LAT_NUM,
        IL.LNGTD_NUM,
    INTO
        latitude,
        longitude,
    FROM 
        ITEM_LOCATION IL
    WHERE 
        IL.ITEM_ID = itemID ;   
END;
```

2)

```
DECLARE
    TYPE t_ref_cursor IS REF CURSOR;
    c_cursor  t_ref_cursor;
    itemID number;
    latitude   ITEM_LOCATION.LAT_NUM%TYPE;
    longitude   ITEM_LOCATION.LNGTD_NUM%TYPE;
BEGIN
    itemID := 294341;

    OPEN c_cursor FOR
        SELECT 
            IL.LAT_NUM,
            IL.LNGTD_NUM, 
        FROM 
            ITEM_LOCATION IL
        WHERE 
            IL.ITEM_ID = itemID ; 
    CLOSE c_cursor; 
END;
```

Does anyone know how either/both of these blocks can return as if it were the SELECT above?

Comment: why cant you just execute the query as a prepared statmenet ? you are not doing anything out of the ordernary in these blocks.

Comment: You might check out this question . . . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455566/display-select-results-inside-anonymous-block.

Comment: @haki - I do not have access to do create on app's DB. Companies' separation of duty and the DBA is not going to be able to get to it soon enough. I wanted to patch it for moment until DBA gets back with prepared statement. This is something I thought wouldn't take long but has become a real pain. Searched Google loads and can only find ability in prepared/stored functionality. Lots of docs talk about 'returning' values through anonymous blocks but with respect to DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line. But this is not actually returning the value as a SELECT would, it is printing the value. Thank you.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - Pascal was trying to debug block and DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line worked as he only needed to view data in console but I need to return the data as if the SELECT was executed. Thank you.

Comment: @JamesGallagher: Would an SQL Plus script with substitution variables work, such as `SELECT IL.LAT_NUM, IL.LNGTD_NUM
FROM ITEM_LOCATION IL
WHERE IL.ITEM_ID = &ITEMID;`

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - Unfortunately not in my circumstances but thank you for the comment :)

Comment: @JamesGallagher: Why not? What is executing this code that it needs a result set?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - Thank you for your comment. I am using Apache SOLR's DataImportHandler, where anything other than a query is not supported (issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1262). The anonymous block might not work either, but I wanted to try it... I thought it would be quick to check :) It turned out not to be so quick...

Comment: @haki - I misunderstood what you meant when you said 'prepared'... my bad... long day :) Just to note, I found the following open issue (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1262). It looks like SOLR's DataImportHandler cannot handle a prepared or stored procedure (no need for DBA now). It very well might not be able to handle an anonymous block either but worth a shot as the version count in the plain SELECT is very high and using a lot of the DB's shared pool (300MB). Moving the literal to a bind variable will solve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to change into an anonymous block ... in order to remove the
>   use of the literal into a bind variable

Why do you think you need to use an anonymous block to use a bind variable? And both of your blocks still have the value `294341` hard-coded anyway; your `select` is using a bind variable within the block but is generating a new block every time really much of an improvement on what you had?

As @haki said many hours ago, you cam just use a prepared statement with a bind variable:

```
PreparedStatement pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT IL.LAT_NUM, IL.LNGTD_NUM :
    + "FROM ITEM_LOCATION IL "
    + "WHERE IL.ITEM_ID = ?");
pStmt.setInt(1, 294341);
```

... and then execute the query and process the result set as you presumably are already. (From your reply to haki's comment you seem to be confusing a prepared statement - which is a Java/JDBC construct - with a stored procedure in the database).

Here's a simple standalone example against the demo `HR` schema's `EMP` table:

import java.sql.*;
import java.text.*;
import oracle.jdbc.*;
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;

```
public class JamesGallagher
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException
    {
        Connection conn;
        OracleDataSource ds = new OracleDataSource();
        ds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:scott/oracle@127.0.0.1:1521:orcl");
        conn = ds.getConnection();

        PreparedStatement pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(
            "select ename, sal from emp where sal > ?");
        pStmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(args[0]));

        ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + ": " + rs.getInt(2));
        }

        try { rs.close(); } catch ( Exception ex ) {}
        try { pStmt.close(); } catch ( Exception ex ) {}
        try { conn.close(); } catch ( Exception ex ) {}
        conn = null;
    }
}
```

I can compile that with `javac JamesGallagher.java` and execute with `java JamesGallagher 1500` and it prints the results based on the bound value:

```
ALLEN: 1600
JONES: 2975
BLAKE: 2850
CLARK: 2450
SCOTT: 3000
KING: 5000
FORD: 3000
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. I was hoping not to get into the 'why' as it is long winded. I am using Apache SOLR and prepared statements are not supported (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1262). The anonymous block might not work either, but I wanted to try it... I thought it would be quick to check :) The variables are hard coded for the above S.O. examples, they would not be in the actual code. Reason for bind variable: the version count in the plain SELECT is very high and using a lot of the DB's shared pool (300MB). Thank you for you comment though, I did pick @haki up wrong :)