# Column names in an empty Oracle REF CURSOR

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, ref-cursor

In PL/SQL, I can use a trick like this one here to find out name/value pairs for every column in a row from a `REF CURSOR`:

[TO_CHAR of an Oracle PL/SQL TABLE type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265160/to-char-of-an-oracle-pl-sql-table-type)

That's an awesome trick. But it doesn't work when the `REF CURSOR` is empty, such as this one here (that's just an example. The real cursor doesn't select from `DUAL`):

```
OPEN cursor FOR SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE 1 = 0;
```

Does an empty `REF CURSOR` even have column name/type information?

Comment: It might be called COLUMN_VALUE.

Comment: @Steve: Always? I'm actually not selecting from `DUAL`. That was just an example

Comment: Ok, well it's been my experience that unnamed columns are given the name COLUMN_VALUE. Not sure if that applies to your case or I'm just barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @Lukas, if there are no rows to process in a cursor, I'm not sure what info you're expecting as output from the printCur procedure?  What do you mean "it doesn't work" exactly?  Maybe I'm misunderstanding u here

Comment: @tbone, when I execute `SELECT 1 AS one FROM DUAL WHERE 1=0` via JDBC, I actually get the column name `one` in the `ResultSet` meta data, even if there are no rows. But that's not the case for `ResultSet` fetched from `REF CURSOR`. So I was actually wondering if that's a problem at the PL/SQL level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I've tried that solution without rows, and you're right.
From my limited point of view, I think here we need **two different methods** to retrieve columns' names and values.

1) Dbms_sql package to retrieve the columns' names.

2) The **[tbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265160/to-char-of-an-oracle-pl-sql-table-type)** method to retrieve the data.

---

**Procedure**

```
create or replace procedure demo(sqlText in varchar2) is
    refCur sys_refcursor;
    curId  integer;
    cnt    number;
    ret    dbms_sql.desc_tab;
    recTab dbms_sql.desc_tab;
    FORMAT_STRING constant pls_integer := 20;

    procedure printDescTab(desctab in sys.dbms_sql.desc_tab) is
    begin
        -- do what you want with the columns
        for i in 1 .. desctab.count
        loop
            dbms_output.put(lpad(desctab(i).col_name, FORMAT_STRING));
        end loop;
        dbms_output.new_line;
    end printDescTab;

    procedure PrintCur(cv in sys_refcursor) is
    begin
        for c in ( --select t2.COLUMN_VALUE.getrootelement() name,
                  select EXTRACTVALUE(t2.COLUMN_VALUE, 'node()') value
                  from   table(XMLSEQUENCE(cv)) t
                         ,table(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(COLUMN_VALUE, '/ROW/node()'))) t2)
        loop
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put(lpad(c.VALUE, FORMAT_STRING));
        end loop;
        dbms_output.new_line;
        dbms_output.new_line;
    end;

begin
    dbms_output.put_line('dynamic sql: ' || sqlText);
    curId := dbms_sql.open_cursor();
    --  checks for sql injection to do...
    dbms_sql.parse(curId, sqlText, dbms_sql.native);
    dbms_sql.describe_columns(curId, cnt, recTab);
    printDescTab(recTab);
    dbms_sql.close_cursor(curId);

    open refCur for sqlText;
    PrintCur(refCur);
    close refCur;
exception
    when others then
        if dbms_sql.is_open(curId) then
           dbms_sql.close_cursor(curId);
        end if;
        if refCur%isopen then
            close RefCur;
        end if;
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode || ' - ' || sqlerrm);
end demo;
```

**Test**

```
declare
    sqlText varchar2(2000);
begin
    sqlText := 'select 1 as one, 2 as two  from  dual where 1=0';
    demo(sqlText);
    sqlText   := 'select name, type || chr(13) type' -- chr(13) specific ASCII Carriage return
                ||' from   user_plsql_object_settings'
                ||' where name not like ''%$%'' and  rownum <= 10';      
    demo(sqlText);   
    sqlText := 'select 1 as one, 2 as two  from  dual ';                  
    demo(sqlText);

exception
    when others then
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode || ' - ' || sqlerrm);
end;
```

**Result**

```
dynamic sql: select 1 as one, 2 as two  from  dual where 1=0
                 ONE                 TWO


dynamic sql: select name, type || chr(13) type from   user_plsql_object_settings where name not like '%$%' and  rownum <= 10
                NAME                TYPE
     ADD_JOB_HISTORY          PROCEDURE
    AFT_INS_TEST_TRG            TRIGGER
    BEF_DEL_TEST_TRG            TRIGGER
    BEF_INS_TEST_TRG            TRIGGER
            BETWNSTR           FUNCTION
                BOOL           FUNCTION
    CACHED_FIBONACCI           FUNCTION
               DEBUG            PACKAGE
               DEBUG       PACKAGE BODY
          DEBUG_TEST          PROCEDURE


dynamic sql: select 1 as one, 2 as two  from  dual 
                 ONE                 TWO
                   1                   2
```

Comment: Crazy! So with 11g, I'm prepared for every type of cursor now! :)

Comment: I was just thinking that these little things, together the view "user_identifier"(11g), dbms_application_info and with a (little) effort, could lead me to a great code instrumentation procedure. Or you have already written? :-)

Comment: Sweet! Go ahead and write that procedure! :)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no way of getting metadata from a `REF CURSOR` directly from PL/SQL. Curiously, a `REF CURSOR` maps to a Java's `ResultSet`, which can be queried for metadata calling its `ResultSet.getMetaData` method.

So you could generate a Java's stored procedure to do that for you. [Here](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1922797�) you can find an example.

Another option is convert the cursor to a numeric cursor using `DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER` (only in 11g), which can be asked for metadata with the [DBMS_SQL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm) package.

Comment: I didn't mention the Java part, but actually you cannot call `ResultSet.getMetaData` on an empty `REF CURSOR`. That will throw an exception :-/ That's the original reason I asked the question for. +1 for guessing that right :)

Comment: It turns out that an empty ref cursor never gets instantiated, that's why it doesn't work. I didn't know that, so thanks for the warning. It seems the kind of error that you forgets to unittest :-)

Comment: Exactly! I added the test and *bang* ! :)