# Get alias names form stored procedure in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Is there any way to get only the alias name that is used in a select statement of an stored procedure? I want to create entities using that select statement.

Example:

```
procedure Getnames(namerecords out Sys_refcursors)
as
begin 
open namerecords for
select 
  N.First_name    FirstName,
  N.SecondName    Secondname
from  Names
End Getnames;
```

I want to get only the `Firstname` ,`secondname` as a result by passing only the stored procedure names.

Are there any system tables which store this information?

Comment: The result of that query will only give you `FirstName` and `Secondname`, what are you expecting? Also, you haven't used the `P_nameId` parameter. And, your query will fail because you haven't applied the alias `N` in the from clause.

Comment: without running this Sp i want to get alias name from any sys tables.if i have more than 20 sp's in a package i want to get all the alias name by passing only the sp name from any sys table which store this information.

Comment: sys tables don't have "alias names" except when you query them. I think I don't really understand what you're trying to do with this procedure.

Comment: I want to create properties in c# using alias names.so i want to get all the alias names in a SP if its SP name is given.I hope u can understand my requirement.

Comment: Why not just use SQL, instead of refcursors? In general they seem to be very overused, particularly where people believe that running lots of small queries is better then running one larger query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get column names from procedure result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717717/get-column-names-from-procedure-result)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dummy_proc
AS
    CURSOR dummy_cur is 
        SELECT  dummy AS dummy_alias1, dummy AS dummy_alias2,dummy dummy_alias3
        ,       dummy AS dummy_alias4
        ,   dummy  dummy_alias5
        ,dummy  dummy_alias6
        ,dummy  dummy_alias7
        FROM    DUAL;
BEGIN
    NULL;
END;
-- PROCEDURE DUMMY_PROC compiled

WITH all_src AS
(
        SELECT  owner, name, type, line, text
        FROM    all_source
        WHERE   owner = USER
        AND     type  = 'PROCEDURE'
        AND     name  = 'DUMMY_PROC'
)
, conditions AS
(
        SELECT  line AS con_start
        ,       LEAD(line) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY line) AS con_end
        FROM    all_src
        WHERE   (INSTR(UPPER(text), 'SELECT') > 0 OR INSTR(UPPER(text), 'FROM') > 0)
)
, one_line AS
(
        SELECT  LISTAGG(text, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY line) AS select_line
        FROM    all_src
        WHERE   EXISTS
                (
                    SELECT  1
                    FROM    conditions
                    WHERE   line >= con_start
                    AND     line <  con_end
                )
)
SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE
        (
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(select_line, '\w+(\s+\,|\,|$)', 1, 1) || ' ' ||
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(select_line, '\w+(\s+\,|\,|$)', 1, 2) || ' ' ||
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(select_line, '\w+(\s+\,|\,|$)', 1, 3) || ' ' ||
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(select_line, '\w+(\s+\,|\,|$)', 1, 4) || ' ' ||
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(select_line, '\w+(\s+\,|\,|$)', 1, 5) || ' ' ||
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(select_line, '\w+(\s+\,|\,|$)', 1, 6) || ' ' ||
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(select_line, '\w+(\s+\,|\,|$)', 1, 7)
         -- REGEXP_SUBSTR(select_line, '\w+(\s+\,|\,|$)', 1, 8)
         -- REGEXP_SUBSTR(select_line, '\w+(\s+\,|\,|$)', 1, 9)
        ,   '\s+\,\s+'
        ,   ', '
        ) AS r_substr
FROM    one_line
;

-- dummy_alias1, dummy_alias2, dummy_alias3, dummy_alias4, dummy_alias5, dummy_alias6, dummy_alias7
```

Comment: +1 This may be good enough in this case.  But parsing SQL is rarely 100% accurate.  For example, "dummy+1 as dummy_alias8", would not work.

Comment: In Oracle the plus sign would not be recommended. You could use it with the quotation signs. I know that in SQL Server or MySQL it is common practice to use “[ ]” or “` `” but not in Oracle.

Comment: Sorry, my example was ambiguous.  I should have used the code formatting instead of quotation marks.  What I meant was that if you use an expression instead of just a column, the code will not work.  E.g., `dummy+1 as dummy_alias8`.

Comment: I added two columns: **dummy+1 dummy_alias8,SYSDATE+ 1 dummy_alias9** and it is working fine (... dummy_alias8, dummy_alias9). One of the improvements to make would be replacing hardcoded number of columns with CONNECT BY clause. If you have time feel free to add any changes and post it as answer I do not mind.

Comment: Sorry, here's a [real example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c4007/1).  You can improve the SQL, but there are always going to be weird queries that won't parse properly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer is 
`select * from all_source where name='YOUR_SP'`.

But you should do some text processing to find the aliases, and the procedures should have the same format.